# Count and display the column headers that are Categorical in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame - Train_data and I would like to get the count of number of Categorical Variables and display those column headers using R language.

Kindly please post your suggestions about any functions or packages.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post an example of your data?

Comment: @SRivero I have almost 800 columns in the dataset. That's why this trouble. I could use is.factor() but that will take some time for me to do it one by one.

Comment: try ? `sapply(Train_data,function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: @wen that provides the number of unique elements in each of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a bunch of ways using only base R. First one that comes to mind for me is to use summary() to get the range, quartiles and mean of numeric variables and counts of categorical variables:

```
x<-summary(iris)
```

This is a good thing to do anyway prior to further analysis.

After that, take your summary object and find the column names where you aren't getting a minimum reported:

```
y<- colnames(x)[substring(x[1,],1,4)!="Min."]
cat(y)
```

These are your categorical variable names.

Edit: Now that I've thought about it a little more, I have another way I like better.

```
z<-rep("",ncol(iris))
 for(i in 1:ncol(iris)){
 z[i]<-class(get(colnames(iris)[i]))
 }

 df.content<-data.frame(varnames=colnames(iris),data.type=z)
```

Comment: Thanks sir :) Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: No problem. Now that I've thought about it a little more I actually have a better way. I would do something like this:> z<-rep("",ncol(iris))
 for(i in 1:ncol(iris)){
 z[i]<-class(get(colnames(iris)[i]))
 }
 
 df.content<-data.frame(varnames=colnames(iris),data.type=z)